# Error:1004 unable to get week num property of the worksheet function class

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, week-number

Below is the code i have been using.

```
StartWeekNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(StartDate, 21)
EndWeekNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(EndDate, 21)
```

This code worked properly in excel 2010 version, when it comes to 2007 it is getting runtime error.

Comment: What are `StartDate` and `EndDate`? As a test, what happens if you omit the `, 21`?

Comment: i have defined startdate and end date instead of giving the fixed date